# 2011 Toyota Sienna Intermittent Starting Problems

Tags: toyota, starting, sienna

I have a 2011 Toyota Sienna (~50,000 miles) that has intermittent starting problems. The car also sometimes starts then immediately dies sometimes.

Here is a [video](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rqfNY.jpg) of the issue.

Here is another [video](https://i.stack.imgur.com/td8gZ.jpg) of the car barely able to start after a few minutes.

Things I’ve tried.

1. I got the battery tested at a few places. The first place told me it was a “good battery” but the voltage was a tad bit low. They suggested putting it on a trickle charger. I drove it on the highway for a while to attempt to recharge it and then took it to another shop where they also said it was a “good battery” and didn’t mention charging it.
2. When I use my Li-Ion booster battery it helps the car start.
3. I used Sea Foam in hopes of helping the issue.
4. I changed the engine air filter.
5. I got the alternator tested at a shop (they checked if the voltage dropped when the car was turned on with load). The alternator was deemed good.
6. I got the starter tested at a shop where they tested the voltage drop when starting the car. The starter was deemed good.
7. There is no check engine light so I assume there are no major error codes to be read.

I did some research to see what else could cause this issue and the only thing that seems like it could be is the intake temperature sensor.

Comment: Check fuel pump pressure if you can, may be a failing fuel pump. Any codes in the computer?

Comment: Check the fuel filter.